# Information about constant class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, oop, constants

Hi all im working on ray tracing algorithm and I want to show different possibilities by shooting lines from different positions in Three.js. I just wanted some information about this line of code below and how to use it or do not use it at all.

```
const Ray_Techniques = class { 

    MANAGER() {
       return{
          FRT: function(){
              return{
                  //Shoot lines in stage entry
              };
          },
          BRT: function(){
              return{
                  //Shoot lines in stage entry (different algorithm)
              };
          }
       };
    }

    hide_show_repeat_MANAGER(){
        return{
             //hide, show, repeat each stage
        };
    }
};
```

Is that okay to use ? I'm new to Object Oriented Javascript. I just want to let the user repeat the stage by recalling some of those functions and also hide/show a specific algorithm according to the stage (slider-value). Also is the 'const'class going to affect all these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that okay to use?

No, it's not OK to use a `class` here at all. You only need classes if you have multiple instances with shared methods and different configuration or mutable state. For what you've shown in your question, a simple object will suffice:

```
const rayTechniques = { 
    manager: {
        FRT() {
            … //Shoot lines in stage entry
        },
        BRT() {
            … //Shoot lines in stage entry (different algorithm)
        }
    },
    hide_show_repeat() {
        … //hide, show, repeat each stage
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Bergi. Now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The only differences will be that you cannot reassign `Ray_Techniques` to another value since it is defined as a `const`. A class defined as `class Ray_Techiques {}` would allow you to reassign the class name `Ray_Techniques` to something else.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description):

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its properties) can be altered.

In my opinion the `const` declaration detracts from code readability vs named class.